# Find operation (AJAX request) rejected, not seen in the wire

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application, I am doing several `find` operations. All of them are working, except one, which is being rejected. For debugging purposes, I am sending the requests during startup of the application:

```
preloadData : function () {
    SettingsApp.Node.find();
    SettingsApp.Locator.find();
    SettingsApp.Phonelocation.find();
    SettingsApp.User.find(CNST.ME_FAKE_DOC_ID);
    SettingsApp.Company.find(CNST.MY_ORG_FAKE_DOC_ID);
},
```

And this is how it looks in the console:

[image: [ajax call rejected]

As you can see, all requests are `isFullfilled` except the last one which is `isRejected`. The `rejectedReason` says only "error".

What could be causing this? This is no backend problem, since the request is not being sent at all. The only thing I can think of is the adapter configuration, since `companies` has an irregular plural:

```
SettingsApp.Adapter.configure('plurals', {
    voice_menu : 'voicemenus',
    profile    : 'profile',
    company    : 'companies',
});
```

But this is being used properly, it seems. What could else be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason why your `GET` request is rejected, but as a quick workaround for debugging purposes you could do the following to get more info on the errors that are occurring:

```
Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  console.log(error.stack);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. And now, magically, the requests are fulfilled! I have changed nothing! Baffled! I'll leave the RSVP debugging on for future problems. Unrelated, but thanks to that I have seen that there are some `TransitionAborted` errors happening, no idea why. I'll also leave the  question open, in case somebody can suggest why are requests being rejected.